# Remove duplicates and carriage returns from a SINGLE cell

Tags: excel

I've seen macros that come very close to addressing my problem, but can't seem to make them work for my situation.  I have a series of cells to apply a fix.  Each SINGLE cell has exact duplicate names, separated ONLY by a carriage return. Is there a macro to remove the duplicate names AND the carriage returns from the cell? Here's an example.

Current cell A1:
John P. Doe
John P. Doe
John P. Doe
John P. Doe

Current cell A2:
Mark J. Smith
Mark J. Smith

Desired outcome for Cell A1:
John P. Doe

Desired outcome for Cell A2:
Mark J. Smith

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried? And also any other methods and what did/didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Place this in B1 and drag down:

`=Trim(LEFT(A1,SEARCH(CHAR(13),A1,1)))`.

`Char(13)` is the equivalent of a carriage return.  This will look at all the text *left* of the first carriage return, and return that text.

If they're not truly carriage returns, but instead a new line, use `Char(10)`.

Comment: This may work fine. But there is the possibility that it won't and also the possibility that it will work but include an artifact. Multiple lines can be from a CR or from a LF or from a concatenation of CRLF.

Comment: But it is likely that they are all the same, so OP just needs to determine which works and then apply this answer.

Comment: @ExcelHero - couldn't he also copy the "line return" and paste that in place of `Char(13)` (with quotes of course)?  I have seen that done before for what look like spaces, but are a special space character.  I don't think it'd work though for line breaks/carriage returns, but figure I'd ask.

Comment: It won't work because you cannot place quotes around a line break. OP will need to use CHAR(10) or CHAR(13) or CHAR(13)&CHAR(10). Could also place any of those in a cell and refer to the cell. Could also define in the Name Manager as a named constant.

Comment: The Char(10) worked, thus they must have been "new lines" instead of "carriage returns".  Thanks so much.

Comment: @BruceWayne -- UPDATE:  While this worked, I now discovered that it leaves behind a blank "new line" under the final output.  It's wreaking havoc on my mail merge project.  Any ideas how to prevent the extra line?

Comment: @user5556423 - do you mean that in the cell with the formula, it leaves the word but also a blank new line under it?

Comment: @BruceWayne - Yes, that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: That's interesting, it's not for me (when I enter a cell, type something and hit `ALT ENTER` and type again).  What if you take the return cell, copy and paste values (the 123 symbol)?  Does it still keep the extra line?